# All my chrome extension popups show only as small empty boxes

Tags: google-chrome

For whatever reason all my Chrome extensions no longer work properly, all the icons are there, but when I click any of them the popup box is just a tiny square with no content. Restarting the browser, and disabling/re enabling them did not fix the problem.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

This is using Chrome Version 27.0.1430.3 dev-m. Perhaps it is just a problem with this build, but I did not notice the problem directly following the last update, it has been a few day, so that seems unlikely.

However on the same machine running Version 27.0.1432.0 canary it works just fine.

Comment: This happens to me too, but only if Chrome is on my far-right monitor. It also affects the "bookmark" window.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same issue and I resolved it by:

1. Go to chrome://flags/
2. Then look for '***GPU compositing on all pages***' and change the value from Default to Disabled

[image]

This solved the issue for me. This issue seems after the latest dev update to Google Chrome. This is a temporary workaround.

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: Glad that it helped. :)

Comment: This flag no longer appears in the list - using version 48.0.2564.103

Comment: This happen to me in my secondary screen. If I use chrome on my primary screen it works.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me in Dec 2015. I went to the chrome://flags page and clicked the "Reset all to defaults" button and that cleared this up for me.

Comment: The answer above didn't work for me as the "GPU compositing on all pages" doesn't exist. Reset worked for me too, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Chrome after a recent update (June 17), certain sites like Yahoo mail would only show the icons as boxes. I disabled/removed a Chrome extension called ForceFonts and the problem went away.